# three.js skybox: obvious corners and lots of distortion

Tags: javascript, three.js, skybox

Today I've been experimenting with building my first ever skybox in three.js. I've read a lot of tutorials and the code I've ended up with is based on this one: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/15/lets-do-a-sky/
I did make a few changes in order to allow for the images to load first, and to make it compatible with the version of three.js which I am using.

I've overcome a lot of small problems to get to the point I am currently at, but cannot find any answer to my current issue despite having searched quite hard. My problem is that despite using purpose-built skybox textures downloaded from the internet, it is glaringly obvious that my skybox is a cube with corners and edges. The textures appear heavily distorted and are not at all convincing.

Here is a screenshot of how my skybox looks:
[image: Here is a screenshot of my skybox]

And here is a link to the site from which I downloaded the images:
http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=Cubemap&item=Yokohama3
As you can see, in their preview it looks much better.

I've tried this with a few different downloaded textures and every time it is very obvious that you are looking at the inside of a cube.

Here's my code (I'm including all my code, not just the section which creates the skybox):

```
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var renderer;

    function createRenderer () {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0)
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        //renderer.shadowCameraNear = 0.5;
        //renderer.shadowCameraFar = 500;
    }

    function createCamera () {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            45, 
            window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
            0.1, 1000
        );
        camera.position.x = 50;
        camera.position.y = 30;
        camera.position.z = 40;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    }

    function createPlane () {
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xcccccc,
        })
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(40, 40)

        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        plane.receiveShadow = true;
        plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2
        plane.position.y = -6;
        scene.add(plane)
    }

    function createLight () {
        var spotLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        spotLight.position.set( 0, 50, 20 );
        spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
        spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5
        spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 0;
        spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 100;
        spotLight.shadowCameraLeft = -50;
        spotLight.shadowCameraRight = 50;
        spotLight.shadowCameraTop = 50;
        spotLight.shadowCameraBottom = -50;
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(spotLight);
    }

    function createSkyboxAndSphere () { 

        var urlPrefix = "Yokohama3/";
        var urls = [ urlPrefix + "posx.jpg", urlPrefix + "negx.jpg",
            urlPrefix + "posy.jpg", urlPrefix + "negy.jpg",
            urlPrefix + "posz.jpg", urlPrefix + "negz.jpg" ];
        var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls , undefined, function () {;

            var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["cube"];
            var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );
            shader.uniforms['tCube'].value = textureCube;   // textureCube has been init before
            var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                fragmentShader    : shader.fragmentShader,
                vertexShader  : shader.vertexShader,
                uniforms  : shader.uniforms,
                depthWrite : false,
                side: THREE.BackSide,
            });


            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100)
            var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
            scene.add(skybox)


            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                color: "red",
                envMap: textureCube,
                reflectivity: 0.3,
            })
            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(6, 30, 15)

            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
            sphere.castShadow = true;
            sphere.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add(sphere)

            });
    }

    function init () {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        createRenderer();
        createCamera();
        createLight();
        createPlane ();
        createSkyboxAndSphere ();

        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(renderer.domElement)

        render ()
    }

    function render () {
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        init ();
    }
```

I suspect I am fundamentally misunderstanding something about how cubemapping and skyboxes work - I am very new to this in particular and javascript in general and am aware of huge gaps in my knowledge.

My apologies if the answer to this is obvious and/or the question has been asked before, and a pre-emptive thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera needs to be in the center of the skybox -- or at least near the center.

So either move your camera *very close* to the box center, or update the box position every frame to match the camera position.

Or make the skybox *much bigger* relative to the camera offset from the origin.

three.js r.74

Comment: The example linked has been updated in more recent versions and no longer uses a separate scene with two cameras and two render passes. For reference, the old source for r74 can still be viewed on github at: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r74/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap.html

Comment: Thanks, @CoryGross. The outdated link has been removed... The new approach is to assign the cube texture to the `scene.background`, and the renderer will ensure the cube map is properly-positioned relative to the camera.